# Slow internet connection How to investigate?

Tags: networking, 22.04, troubleshooting, tcp-ip

About 2 days ago the internet on my laptop (dell vostro 3550/Ubuntu 22.04) suddenly became pretty slow. The internet is working fine when I connect from an Android phone.

So, how can I investigate the problem? Where to begin?

I appreciate any help.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 28 Apr 2023 22:39 -03 -0300

Booted last: 28 Apr 2023 00:00 -03 -0300

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

### release ###

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

### kernel ###

Linux 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

### desktop ###

Ubuntu

### lspci ###

05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:04b3]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5325]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

### lsusb ###

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 275d:0ba6  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a2c:2d23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ca:181f Ricoh Co., Ltd Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_FHD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. Centrino Advanced-N 6230 Bluetooth adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

### PCMCIA card info ###

### rfkill ###

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

### secure boot ###

EFI variables are not supported on this system

### lsmod ###

dell_laptop            32768  0
iwldvm                311296  0
dell_wmi               24576  1 dell_laptop
mac80211             1314816  1 iwldvm
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,dell_wmi,dell_laptop
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
wmi_bmof               16384  0
iwlwifi               503808  1 iwldvm
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
cfg80211             1044480  3 iwldvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi                    32768  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
video                  65536  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915

### interfaces ###

### ifconfig ###

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp5s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp9s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.9/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp9s0
       valid_lft 83709sec preferred_lft 83709sec
    inet6 fe80::56f1:3be1:a8d8:80a5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

### iwconfig ###

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp9s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"LIVE TIM_9147_2G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'LIVE TIM_9147_2G' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:71   Missed beacon:0

### route ###

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp9s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp9s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.9 metric 600 

### resolv.conf ###

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

### network managers ###

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         974       1  0 14:31 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

## NetworkManager info ###

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp9s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.19.0-41-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               18.168.6.1 6000g2b-6.ucode
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp9s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:09:00.0/net/wlp9s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:09:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp9s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     LIVE TIM_9147_2G
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       d0e7a7c1-84cd-4978-8081-92c18f4d3672
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     65 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.9/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        expiry = 1682816067
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        host_name = F680V9.0
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.9
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::56f1:3be1:a8d8:80a5/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fe80::1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d0e7a7c1-84cd-4978-8081-92c18f4d3672 | LIVE TIM_9147_2G

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp5s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.19.0-41-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp5s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:05:00.0/net/enp5s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:05:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID                    BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE 
LIVE TIM_9147_2G        <MAC 'LIVE TIM_9147_2G' [AC1]>  Infra  3     2422 MHz  260 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       yes     *      
LIVE TIM_F2C0_2G        <MAC 'LIVE TIM_F2C0_2G' [AC4]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  405 Mbit/s  72      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no             
FREITAS                 <MAC 'FREITAS' [AC3]>  Infra  10    2457 MHz  270 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  WPA2       no             
Multilaser_2.4G_344848  <MAC 'Multilaser_2.4G_344848' [AC2]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  270 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1       no             
ANA                     <MAC 'ANA' [AC5]>  Infra  7     2442 MHz  270 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1       no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

### NetworkManager profiles ###

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LIVE TIM_9147_2G.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LIVE TIM_9147_2G | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=LIVE TIM_9147_2G
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

### Netplan config ###

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

### iw reg get ####

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

### iwlist channels ###

lo        no frequency information.

enp5s0    no frequency information.

wlp9s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)

### iwlist scan ###

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp5s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlp9s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'LIVE TIM_9147_2G' [AC1]>
                    Channel:3
                    Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                    Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LIVE TIM_9147_2G"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000005c4c554632
                    Extra: Last beacon: 156ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Multilaser_2.4G_344848' [AC2]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Multilaser_2.4G_344848"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000007c0cdc91e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 544ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'FREITAS' [AC3]>
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FREITAS"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000005c4cc13e50
                    Extra: Last beacon: 552ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'LIVE TIM_F2C0_2G' [AC4]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LIVE TIM_F2C0_2G"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000003c7e2fb81a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 512ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'ANA' [AC5]>
                    Channel:7
                    Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ANA"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000005440f2cf4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2200ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'LIVE TIM_6D94_2G' [AC6]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LIVE TIM_6D94_2G"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000001c43ab45
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1132ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC '' [AC7]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000005c490c81a9
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1116ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 08 - Address: <MAC 'LIVE TIM_F2B0_2G' [AC8]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=27/70  Signal level=-83 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LIVE TIM_F2B0_2G"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000005c49eccb68
                    Extra: Last beacon: 912ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 09 - Address: <MAC 'LIVE TIM_RCBS_2G' [AC9]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LIVE TIM_RCBS_2G"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000d05e7b19e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 500ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

### module info ###

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwldvm
vermagic:       5.19.0-41-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           force_cam:force continuously aware mode (no power saving at all) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-41-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.19.0-41-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.19.0-41-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:0:disable, 1-15:FW_DBG_PRESET Values, 16:enabled without preset value defined,Debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 16)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-41-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.19.0-41-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

### module parameters ###

[iwldvm]
force_cam: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

grep: /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/enable_ini: Operation not permitted
[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 8
amsdu_size: 0
bt_coex_active: N
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 1
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
### rc.local ###

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

### pm-utils ###

### udev rules ###

### dmesg ###

[ 9674.454120] wlp9s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'LIVE TIM_9147_2G' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 9679.877439] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[ 9679.886568] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1 (repeated 2 times)
[ 9680.661662] wlp9s0: authenticate with <MAC 'LIVE TIM_9147_2G' [AC1]>
[ 9680.661683] wlp9s0: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 9680.664071] wlp9s0: send auth to <MAC 'LIVE TIM_9147_2G' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 9680.666386] wlp9s0: authenticated
[ 9680.669366] wlp9s0: associate with <MAC 'LIVE TIM_9147_2G' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 9680.675139] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'LIVE TIM_9147_2G' [AC1]> (capab=0x1c11 status=0 aid=5)
[ 9680.683478] wlp9s0: associated
[ 9680.717528] wlp9s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'LIVE TIM_9147_2G' [AC1]>
[ 9680.794202] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp9s0: link becomes ready
```